# How to disable SSL if a page url contains a specific word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https, redirect

I have my site running on all over SSL, but I added a games sections which uses the 3rd party games in flash. When I enable SSL it stop working. I am wondersing if how can I only disable the SSL on that specific page which contains "/game/" in the url so that the games will work fine.

I tried this code from insternet in my .htaccess file but not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^game^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:

I tried the answer suggested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On [NC]
RewriteRule ^game http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

It works but when I go the pages contained the word "game" it turns the other pages also to "http" and other pages are become using "http" instead of "https"

Then I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On [NC]
RewriteRule ^game http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

This it starts giving me the message "Page is not redirecting properly" when I go to "game" page url.

I want only the "game" pages to use "http".

EDIT TWO: The FULL .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Need help. Let me know if any duplicate is found, I can not find anyone though. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you have more rules in your .htaccess post complete .htaccess here in question.

Comment: I added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your full .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # except for /game/ enforce https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/game/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # for /game/ enforce http
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /game/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: It gives me the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" with your same htaccess file.

Comment: That means you still have old cache in browser. Test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled. Then monitor in `Network` tab what URL's you see for 301/302 redirects. btw does `/game/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: I tried suggestion by you, using disable cache option as well as private browsing also I am using zend applications in which there are not htaccess files in the modules, and games is a module. There is only one htaccess file on root.

Comment: ok what URL you are entering for testing and what 301/302 redirects you are seeing in `Network` tab of Chrome dev tool with caching disabled?

Comment: I entered my domain name like www.example.com and in network tab I see requests going to https:// www.example.com/ with status code "302 Moved Temporarily" after few redirects with the same 302 status it shows me "This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: There is no `302` in my suggested rules. Are you sure there is no code doing this? Also what is your Apache version? Sometimes if you're behind proxy then `%{HTTPS}` isn't populated.